# Launching dialog activity from services caused 'MainActivity' to also launch

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am designing an app that is used for emergency alerts. The alerts come from a server and a connection to that server is maintained in service.

If the service receives an emergency request from the server it checks to see if a specific activity is open. If it is it lets it know an emergency has been triggered and the activity launches a dialog activity with some options. It then handles results from this new dialog activity.

However, if the service notes that the activity is NOT open I want it to launch the dialog anyway. I know that this isn't good practise but because of the importance of this emergency I don't want to rely on Notifications (which are already in use if the activity is closed to let the user know that the app is still listening for emergencies).

What currently happens is that the below code is executed in the service and the dialog launches. However, the 'main' activity (the only other activity in the app) also opens behind the dialog. What I really want to happen is that either...

1) The service launches the main activity which then opens the dialog so that I can easily capture the results.

2) The service launches only the dialog activity and I use a broadcast receiver to capture results from this activity.

1 would use the mechanics that already exist for capturing results from an activity. However I don't like the idea of chaining the activities together in this way.

2 means I can ignore the main activity all together (because I don't really need it in this instance) but seems more of a get around.

What I am really asking is two things. What is best practise given my circumstances and how do i achieve number 2? Here is the launch code in my service. Notification in this code is referring to the dialog activity that will open.

```
if (MainActivity.isActivityInUI) {
            //Dealt with by activity
            sendMessageAlert(message);

        } else {
            //Launch dialog directly from service
            Intent notification = new Intent(this,
                    EmergencyNotificationActivity.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(MobileMessage.EXTRA_LOCATION_NAME,
                    message.locationName);
            args.putString(MobileMessage.EXTRA_ID,
                    String.valueOf(message.id));
            args.putDouble(MobileMessage.EXTRA_LATITUDE,
                    Double.valueOf(message.latitude));
            args.putDouble(MobileMessage.EXTRA_LONGITUDE,
                    Double.valueOf(message.longitude));


            //and the flag to let the notification know this is from a service...
            args.putBoolean(EXTRA_FROM_SERVICE, true);

        notification.putExtras(args);

            //add flag because this is being called from outside of an activity
            notification.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |ActivityInfo.LAUNCH_SINGLE_INSTANCE);

            startActivity(notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of trying to show a dialog without visibly showing an Activity, you should consider launching an Activity that is themed like a Dialog. Just apply the following theme: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Dialog (or similar themes) to your EmergencyNotificationActivity. You probably would have to tweak your class to behave like a dialog instead of launching one (which I am assuming is what you're doing currently).

This method would also allow you to not have to check if an Activity already exists.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. My dialog is already a themed dialog activity. I will update the original question to make it clear

Comment: You may want to reconsider some design aspects. Instead of a dialog, why not just a full Activity? If your goal is to completely interrupt the users workflow in favor of an emergency message, a full Activity would be better suited and you can include more content in a full Activity. Similar to the alarm clock.

Comment: Hi there,Yes I could do this. But wouldn't the problem still exist? Or is the problem because the Theme of this activity is dialog?

Comment: If your main activity (the one that shows behind your dialog) was transparent, then you'd be all set right?

Comment: Hi there,it was certainly look ok but I need to use that activity for other things and I don't want it transparent...